# JavaScript one() event handling chaining causes strange errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need your help. I'm currently writing some code to handle a modal behavior like clicking on buttons. For catching multiple events once, I already posted this question:

[JavaScript event handling code get's called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64706859/javascript-event-handling-code-gets-called-multiple-times)

There it said to use the jQuery `.one()` function to only catch one click when opening the popup and clicking one button multiple times. This works great for one button but when I use two buttons, I came up with another error.

First I've changed my event handling to accept multiple events:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('button').click(function() {
        openConfirmationRemodal().one({
            confirmation: function() {
                console.log('Confirmation');
            },
            cancellation: function() {
                console.log('Cancellation');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When I click on a button, my popup opens with two buttons:

[image]

When I click now the <kbd>Nein</kbd> button, the popup closes and the console logs **Cancellation**. When I open the popup again now and click the <kbd>Ja</kbd> button, **Confirmation** get's logged but twice. I really don't understand this and how to fix this..

[image]

If I do this the opposite way, the error is the same but just in a different order:

[image]

Here you have a working example. Somehow the action in die example get's triggered twice (initially). This is different to the normal progress in my browser but I think this depends on the snippet functionality:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('button').click(function() {
    openConfirmationRemodal().one({
      confirmation: function() {
        console.log('Confirmation');
      },
      cancellation: function() {
        console.log('Cancellation');
      }
    });
  });
});

function openConfirmationRemodal() {
  let remodal = $(`[data-remodal-id=test]`);

  remodal.remodal().open();

  return remodal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/remodal@1.1.1/src/remodal.js"></script>
<button>Open Pop-Up</button>
<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="test">
  <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
  <h1>Remodal</h1>
  <p>
    Responsive, lightweight, fast, synchronized with CSS animations, fully customizable modal window plugin with declarative configuration and hash tracking.
  </p>
  <br>
  <button data-remodal-action="cancel" class="remodal-cancel">Cancel</button>
  <button data-remodal-action="confirm" class="remodal-confirm">OK</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show a full working example so we can understand the context you're working in. With regard to the issue, my guess would be that you're somehow binding the same event handlers multiple times

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan added. I was still working on it. Sorry.

Comment: Does anyone has an idea? I really need to get this done v-v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you re-bind the events every time you click the 'Open' button. To fix this define the modal and events just once, when the page loads, and then call `open()` on the modal when the button is clicked. Try this:

```js
let $remodal = $(`[data-remodal-id=test]`);
let modal = $remodal.remodal();

$remodal.on({
  confirmation: function() {
    console.log('Confirmation');
  },
  cancellation: function() {
    console.log('Cancellation');
  }
});

jQuery($ => {
  $('button').click(function() {
    modal.open();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/remodal@1.1.1/src/remodal.js"></script>
<button>Open Pop-Up</button>
<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="test">
  <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
  <h1>Remodal</h1>
  <p>
    Responsive, lightweight, fast, synchronized with CSS animations, fully customizable modal window plugin with declarative configuration and hash tracking.
  </p>
  <br>
  <button data-remodal-action="cancel" class="remodal-cancel">Cancel</button>
  <button data-remodal-action="confirm" class="remodal-confirm">OK</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm, the problem is that I'm using one modal for a lot of things because I don't want to have x amounts of modals. So I open the model each time with different parameters. The way you described makes this impossible. So is there any way to keep my architecture?

Comment: Whats about `$( this ).off();` inside each function?

Comment: In that case change `one()` to `on()`

Comment: This works good for me! If you update your question that way, I can accept it as answer. Thanks for your help yet!